# Text-changing javascript works in tests but not the actual site

Tags: javascript, html

In the test page for my site, this text-changing bit of js works flawlessly, but when I bring it into the actual site, none of the links at the bottom work.

The idea, fully implemented is to have a navigation bar down at the bottom of the page that generates HTML code for the page content. The actual content itself is hidden away inside a javascript string until needed. Then it gets put into a predetermined position on the page.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript Test #9</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("workl").onclick=workf;
        document.getElementById("aboutl").onclick=aboutf;
        document.getElementById("contactl").onclick=contactf;
        document.getElementById("quote").onclick=quotationf;        
    }

    function workf(){
        document.getElementById("para").innerHTML="Primary Changed Paragraph Content";
        quotationf("changed quote content");
        return false;
    }
    function aboutf(){
        document.getElementById("para").innerHTML="Secondary Changed Paragraph Content<br><br><br>";
        quotationf("changed quote content");

        return false;
    }       
    function contactf(){
        document.getElementById("para").innerHTML="Tertiary Changed Paragraph Content";
        quotationf("changed quote content");

        return false;
    }
    function quotationf (input){
        document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML=input;
        return false;
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>

    <p id="quote"> quote content</p>
    <p id="para">Unchanged Paragraph Content</p>    <br>
<a id="workl" href="#"> Click here to change the paragraph content </a><br>
<a id="aboutl" href="#"> Click here to change the paragraph content </a><br>
<a id="contactl" href="#"> Click here to change the paragraph content </a>

</body>
</html>
```

The code not working is here: http://theblankframe.com/tempmobile/index.html

The working test is here: http://theblankframe.com/tempmobile/test2.html

Any help at all would be fantastic. Thanks!

Comment: The code you've given works just fine, as the second link proves. The first link isn't working (assuming I'm supposed to be clicking "Contact Us"), but that isn't the code you've provided. We need that code if we're to try to figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: Also, I think [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) would greatly simplify your code here and prevent possible browser incompatibility issues (I seem to recall there being some with respect to `innerHTML`).

Answer (score 0):

On the production site, I see the error

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to set value of the property 'onclick': object is null or undefined

at the code line

```
document.getElementById("workl").onclick=workf;
```

On the test site, you define an *A* tag with the ID *workl*

```
<a id="workl" href="#"> Click here to change the paragraph content </a>
```

However you do not define such a tag on your production site.

Your JavaScript in production attempts to get the element by ID for an ID that does not exist, and then call a method on that element that was not able to be found.

Comment: This would be better as an edit/addition to the original post than an answer.

Comment: Enhanced to make it a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need an element with id `work1` in your actual site for this to work. This is because the code

```
document.getElementById("workl").onclick=workf;
```

is looking for that element, which it can't find.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here

```
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("workl").onclick=workf; // << error thrown here
document.getElementById("aboutl").onclick=aboutf; //<< aboutl doesnt exist too
document.getElementById("contactl").onclick=contactf;
document.getElementById("quotet").onclick=quotationf;
}
```

There is no element with id `workl` hence attaching an handler on a `null` object throws up an error in `document.getElementById("workl").onclick=workf;` and the rest of the script fails

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you. I didn't know that Javascript used linear execution. I'm still kind of new to it. The site works now after I commented out the first two.

Answer (score 0):

@In production there is no element with id "workl".

A good pratice is verify if you getElementById return something valid.

```
if(document.getElementById("workl")){
   document.getElementById("workl").onclick=workf;
}
```